# Hot reload returns to the first page

Tags: flutter, flutter-hotreload

I have a question about Flutter.
In the application I made myself, log in from the login page and display the next page,
When I edit main.dart and save it, it returns to the first page.
Is it by specification that hot reload should return to the first page instead of working for the current page?

Added 4/18 10:15 JST.
After isolating the cause, it became HotRestart when the device was chrome. If the device is windows, it became HotReload.
Is HotReload not supported in chrome?

Comment: It depends on your code and what changes you made, which you need to share. Since you're reloading main.dart, everything will be rebuilt, but your state should be maintained.

Comment: have you checked this link https://www.dhiwise.com/post/hot-reload-and-hot-restart-in-flutter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hot reload is not supported for Flutter web. [These official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/hot-reload) make it clear that "Flutter web currently supports hot restart but not hot reload." You'll have to use hot restart for now!

Answer (score 1):

In most cases HOT RELOAD work as change on only that page, The app reload is called HOT RESTART.